# WPF DataGrid cell DataTrigger if value is null

Tags: datagrid, datatrigger

I'm trying to come up with a trigger to make changes to DataGrid cell if the content is null but have no clue how to check the content

```
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Could someone please let me know how to bind to cell's contents to check for null?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
         //bind the data using itemsource to datagrid, you can do it in .xaml or in .cs, if you are loading data directly from database then it's easy to bind without viewmodel or object class                   
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _propertyname1}" Value="x:Null">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>



          //.cs for loading data,(if you need)
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Runs.ConString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_cmd, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(_table);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            _datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Late response from me but nevertheless....  I'm looking for a style that can be applicable to to all cells at once not based on binding propertyName.  That's why I was trying to bind to Path=Text.  I finished my project by making this trigger for every column (as you basically showed) but it's not optimail if you can set it to entire DataGrid at once.